# Find string using .include? in ruby code is not the same as IRB result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In irb I can do the follow which is what I expect:

```
irb(main):001:0> "    end     ".include? "  end  " => true
irb(main):002:0> "    end     ".include? "end" => true
irb(main):003:0> "   vendor     ".include? "end" => true
irb(main):004:0> "   vendor     ".include? " end " => false
```

If I have the following code with “end” embedded in a variable named "line",

```
if line.include? "end"
  puts "true when 'end'"
else
  puts "false when 'end'"
end
if line.include? "  end  "
  puts "true when '  end  '"
else
  puts "false when '  end  '"
end
```

I get the following results where as I would expect true in both cases as in irb:

```
Line:      end

true when 'end'
false when '  end  '
```

Comment: Are you sure that `Line:      end` is producing the string `"Line:      end  "` and not `"Line:      end\n"` or something to that effect?

Comment: If `line` is equal to `"end"`, then `line.include?("  end ")` properly evaluates to `false`, because the subset does not include the larger string. In your IRB examples, you are doing the opposite, that is to say, you are asking if a larger string includes the subset.

Comment: `IRB` uses the same Ruby interpreter as when you run your file. How is the `line` variable being assigned? What is its value?

Comment: That solved it. I think you are right about "  end\n"

Comment: Readability is improved when you remove the IRB prompts (e.g., "irb(main):001:0> "). Moreover, if readers want to cut-and-paste your code to test or modify it (perhaps not here), you are requiring each of them to strip out the IRB prompts.